# Permissão negada para criar arquivo no flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Tenho uma aplicação em Flutter que gerar arquivo e compacta no diretório de downloads do Android e disponibiliza para o usuário.
Em Aparelhos com Android 9, foi sem problema, porém ao em aparelhos com Android 10 tenho o seguinte erro:

```
Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot create file, path = 
'/storage/emulated/0/Download/backupPositive2021-03-10 17:23:05.608854.zip' (OS Error: Permission 
denied, errno = 13)
```

Já dei as permissões necessário no AndroidManifest e estou utilizando o "permission_handler" onde verifico se tenho permissão.
O código está assim:

```
var enconder = ZipFileEncoder();
var dataNow = new DateTime.now();
var status = await Permission.storage.status;
if (!status.isGranted) {
  await Permission.storage.request();
}

downloadsDirectory = await DownloadsPathProvider.downloadsDirectory;

enconder.create(
    downloadsDirectory.path + '/backupPositive${dataNow.toString()}.zip');
enconder.addFile(io.File(path));
enconder.close();
```

Comment: Não adianta só pedir a permissão, o usuário tem que dar a permissão. Neste exemplo, por mais bobo que pareça, o usuário liberou o acesso? No seu código não tem qualquer validação quanto ao novo status da permissão após solicitá-la.

Comment: Boa noite e obrigado pela resposta, sim o acesso foi liberado, eu mesmo testei isso em um xiaomi e ao debugar o código, na verificação de permissão a mesma consta como concedida.

Comment: Verifique na documentação se no android 10 não existe nenhuma permissão adicional.

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro, não achei nenhum permissão especial que precisa ser declarada, vi que houve mudanças para Android 10 e 11.